# How to type a BinarySearch method while-loop without break statement?

Tags: java, while-loop, break, infinite

I just finished studying the simple BinarySearch algorithm, but one thing that bugs me is that I was taught that break (and continue) statements are often redundant in Java and you can do with most while-loops without them. But I can't figure out how to get rid of hem from the BinarySearch while-loop below:-

```
public static void BinarySearch(int[] list, int key){
int lo = 0;
int hi = list.length-1;
int mid = 0;
while(lo<=hi){
    mid = lo + (hi-lo) / 2;
    if(key<list[mid])
        hi = mid-1;
    else if(key>list[mid])
        lo = mid+1;
    else {
        System.out.println("Key is found at index = " + mid);
        break;
    }
    if(lo>hi){
        System.out.println("Key doesn't exist in the list");
    }
}
```

Question 1: Why does the loop keeps going on and on if I didn't include the break statement? Shouldn't the variable "lo" eventually become greater than "hi"? How come the last if- conditional can see that, but not the while-loop-conditional?

Question 2: How can I can type the while-loop without needing the break statement?

Answer (score 2):

The basic strategy is to add extra conditions to the loop, and set and use these conditions in the code within the loop.

For example, for the above loop:

```
int keyIndex = -1;

. . .

while ( (lo<=hi) && (keyIndex == -1) ) {
    . . .
    else {
        System.out.println("Key is found at index = " + mid);
        keyIndex = mid;     // <<< 
    }
    . . .
}
```

However, using a break statement for loops such as this is considered an acceptable programming practice by many developers.

Here is a [reddit discussion on the use of break and continue](https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/422l77/is_it_bad_to_use_continue/).

And here is a [question in the sister site on software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58237/are-break-and-continue-bad-programming-practices).

As to why your loop does not exit without the break statement is if the key is found, the value of ***lo*** is not changed. So no, the value of ***lo*** does not necessarily become greater than ***high***.

Comment: Ah, I see. One more question. The new value of keyIndex can be arbitrary (anything that isn't -1), right?
I'll probably stick to breaking such loops instead, though, since this is one of its acceptable usages.

Comment: Yes, I used keyIndex because binary searches are often used to return an item. You can also use a boolean.